# Comparing rows with different DataTypes

Tags: python, pandas

**Background -** I am building a python-based QC script that retrieves data from a platform through an API call, which is then transformed into a pandas `df` before finally computing if rows should be dropped or not based on 2x row criteria. In essence, the biproduct is an Exceptions Report, which leaves rows of data that require investigation.

**Criteria to be tested -**

1. **Criteria #1 explanation** - IF (% Ownership == 100) & IF (Ownership Audit Note ∋ [contains] 'ignore' OR 'Ignore') & (IF Entity ID % == Account # %) THEN drop row.
   **Criteria #1 code** - `df = df[(~(df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore|Ignore'))) & (~(df['% Ownership'] == 100)) & (~(df['Account # %'] == 'Entity ID %'))]`
2. **Criteria #2 (where I need help)** - this is better explained by the below visual, however...I need to firstly test if 'reviewed' or 'Reviewed' is in 'Ownership Audit Note', and then test if contains a partial string (e.g., 0.33) which is also in both 'Entity ID %' and 'Account # %'. If the criteria is met, then the row is dropped.
   [image]

   As you can tell, I am trying to test columns with different datatypes and have no idea how I might achieve this. Can someone put me in the right direction with this and suggest how I might tackle coding this criteria?

**Extract from Dataframe -** here is an extract from `df` with the columns that are tested in the 2x criteria. **Note:** the separator after index position 1 denotes example rows for Criteria 1 and 2:

```
  (float64)       (object)                                       (float64)       (float64) 
  % Ownership     Ownership Audit Note                           Entity ID %     Account # % 
0 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership                        100.0000000     100.0000000
1 100.00          [Ignore] 100% Ownership                          0.0000000       0.0000000  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
2 100.00          [Reviewed] Recurring 67% as of 2022-01-07       67.0000000      67.0000000
3 67.00           [Reviewed: 67%] Recur. as of 2022-01-07         67.0000000      67.0000000
4 100.00          [Review: 67.003%] Recurring 100% Ownership      67.0000000      67.0000000
```

Comment: It would be better if you could provide minimal and reproducible code following this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TấnNguyên - I have provided the code that works and an extract from the dataframe. I am looking for guidance on how I can achieve the desired result, rather than have an issue with my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, given the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "% Ownership": {0: 100.0, 1: 100.0, 2: 100.0, 3: 67.0, 4: 100.0},
        "Ownership Audit Note": {
            0: "[ignore] 100% Ownership ",
            1: "[Ignore] 100% Ownership ",
            2: "[Reviewed] Recurring 67% as of 2022-01-07 ",
            3: "[reviewed: 67%] Recur. as of 2022-01-07",
            4: "[Review: 67.003%] Recurring 100% Ownership:",
        },
        "Entity ID": {
            0: 100.0,
            1: 0.0,
            2: 67.0,
            3: 67.0,
            4: 67.0,
        },
        "Account": {
            0: 100.0,
            1: 0.0,
            2: 67.0,
            3: 67.0,
            4: 67.0,
        },
    }
)
```

Row #3 is the only one which has "reviewed" in "Ownership Audit Note" and the same percentage in "Ownership Audit Note", "Entity ID" and "Account".

Thus, it should dropped, which can be achieved like this:

```py
# 1. Add a temporary column with the percentage, if any, in "Ownership Audit Note".
# Here, Pandas str.extract method is used in conjunction with a regex pattern meaning: 
# "a percentage, like 67% or 67.xxx%, in a string that begins and ends with brackets".
# mask1 garantees that this string contains the word "reviewed", so no need to specify
# that in the regex expression.
mask1 = df["Ownership Audit Note"].str.lower().str.contains("reviewed")
df["value"] = df.loc[mask1, "Ownership Audit Note"].str.extract(
    pat=r"\[\D*(\d+\.?\d*)%\]"
)
df["value"] = df["value"].astype("float")

# 2. Remove lines that match all conditions
mask2 = (
    ~df["value"].isna()
    & (df["Entity ID"] == df["value"])
    & (df["Account"] == df["value"])
)
df = df[~mask2].drop(columns="value")
```

So that row #3 is now removed:

```py
print(df)

# Output
   % Ownership                         Ownership Audit Note  Entity ID  Account
0        100.0                     [ignore] 100% Ownership       100.0    100.0
1        100.0                     [Ignore] 100% Ownership         0.0      0.0
2        100.0   [Reviewed] Recurring 67% as of 2022-01-07        67.0     67.0
4        100.0  [Review: 67.003%] Recurring 100% Ownership:       67.0     67.0
```

Comment: Thank you Laurent - please could you explain what `pat=r"\[\D*(\d+\.?\d*)%\]"` is doing?

Comment: I've added new comments in my answer. Also, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html and https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html to know more, and https://regex101.com/ to experiment on your own. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Lauren - it's weird because whilst your example works, when using with a larger dataframe, I get a `IndexedError` which references `df = df[~mask2].drop(columns="value")` Any suggestions?

Comment: No, sorry. You could enclose this line in a try/except statement and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you and one final question...If the percentage in `Entity ID` or `Account` has zero decimal places(e.g., 50 rather than 50.00' because I changed rounding to zero decimal plces) do I need to make any changes to the code?

Comment: This case is accounted for (that's what `\.?\d*` means), so no change needed.

Comment: Code works great now, thanks Lauren for all your help